# VBA Excel - Loop output results in column groups of 3

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sub that does some calculations similar to this:

```
Sub loop_it()
    For k = 1 to 3
        For j=1 to 100
            a = 1*k
            b = k+j
            c = j*j
            ' Currently, this will overwrite the columns with pattern 2-4, 3-5, 4-6, but I want
            ' 2nd-4th columns(k=1), then 5-7 (k=2), then 8-10 (k=3)
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Cells(j, k + 1).Value = a
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Cells(j, k + 2).Value = b
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Cells(j, k + 3).Value = c
        Next j
    Next k
End Sub
```

As noted in the code, my current method will output to columns in a stepwise fashion. I am trying to print to the first group of 3 columns when k=1, then the next 3 when k=2, etc.

How can I use k to output in the correct location? Should I advance k at the end and use range.offset?

Comment: Have another variable (lets say `iC`). Now set the value of `iC` to 2 or 5 or 8 based on the value of `k`. Then you can replace `...Cells(j, k + 1).Value` to `...Cells(j, iC).Value`, `...Cells(j, iC).offset(,1).Value`, `...Cells(j, iC).offset(,2).Value` respectively

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Step` feature of the `For..Next` loop:

```
   For k = 1 To 7 Step 3
```

`k` now takes the values 1, 4 and 7.

But now these lines are wrong:;

```
 a = 1*k
 b = k+j
```

so use:

```
 a = (k-1)/3+1
 b = (k-1)/3+1+j
```

instead.

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/fornext-statement